# Ошибка "near "ON": syntax error" при запросе к БД SQLite

Tags: delphi, sqlite

Делаю запрос к БД SQLite через `TSQLQuery.ExecSQL`. Запрос использует команду INSERT.

```
INSERT INTO Clients(ind_num, date_registration) 
VALUES (0, '2019-03-27 12:30:25') 
ON CONFLICT(ind_num) DO UPDATE SET 
date_registration= '2019-03-27 12:30:25' 
WHERE ind_num=0;
```

Вылетаем ошибка near "ON": syntax error. 
Подскажите, почему?
В DB Browser команда отрабатывает нормально.

*Разработка программы на Rad Studio 10.2. Delphi.*

Comment: Если сервер понимает, а через коннектор нет - это может быть проблема коннектора. Он же не бездумно шлёт запросы на сервер, а что-то там себе соображает и проверяет... и не всегда правильно. Уже сталкивались. На то же намекает и текст ошибки - не от сервера он...

Comment: Приведите код, как вы формируете и отправляете этот запрос. Ошибка вероятно там (не экранированые ' или что-то похожее). Также приведите в вопросе полный текст ошибки

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. С экранированием все в порядке. Вот код из Watch List: 'INSERT INTO Clients(ind_num, date_registration) VALUES (0, ''2019-03-27 12:30:25'') ON CONFLICT(ind_num) DO UPDATE SET date_registration = ''2019-03-27 12:30:25'' WHERE ind_num=0; '.   Я думаю что причина в TSQLQuery. Он не знает такой команды.

Comment: https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html Скобочки с (int_num) лишние

Comment: И вообще в SQLite нет конструкции ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE ... Надо ON CONFLICT REPLACE видимо

Comment: Alexander Chernin. Вот ссылка на ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE: https://sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html   Попробовал убрать скобки - та же ошибка.

Comment: Могу только предположить, что вы не взяли в кавычки нуль - `VALUES ('0', '2019-03-27 12:30:25')`.